# Programmatically adjust plot width to accommodate y-axis numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I'm drawing a plot where the numbers on the y-axis can vary wildly and need a way to programmatically determine a good plot width so they fit. I'm currently using the following hideous hack but it's not very robust. For example, if `ymin` and `ymax` are 1 and 2 then those are both 1-digit numbers but the actual tick labels will be things like "1.3". Is there a way to get the list of tick labels that matplotlib will actually be using, given just `ymin` and `ymax`?

```
ymin, ymax = 1, 1e8

nd = max(len(str(ymin)),  # number of digits (at most) in y-axis numbers
         len(str(ymax)))
wN = .05 + .01*nd # width of the numbers on the y-axis ticks (ymin to ymax)

plt.axes([wN, .06, 1-wN-.01, 1-.12]) # [left, bottom, width, height]
plt.ylabel("the y-axis label")
yticker = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter()
yticker.set_scientific(False)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(yticker)

plt.axis([0, 9, ymin, ymax])
```

[image: Plot with not enough room left for the y-axis tick labels]

Answer (score 2):

To get the tick values use

```
plt.xticks()
plt.yticks()
```

This will show you the values in the plot. You can change them manually, for example

```
plot.yticks(linspace(ymin,ymax,10))
```

will give you 10 evenly spaced ticks between `ymin` and `ymax`.

There is a way to manually set the labels. For example you might want the following tick values

```
tick_vals = numpy.linspace(0,1,4)
```

to appear as `[0.0, .33, 0.67, 1.0]` which you can achieve by setting the tick labels using the `round` function. The argument `2` means round to two digits:

```
tick_labels = [round(tick_vals[i],2) for i in range(len(tick_vals))]
```

Then set the tick labels using

```
plt.yticks(tick_vals, tick_labels)
```

The actual y-axis will scale to match the values set by `tick_vals`, but they will be relabeled according to `tick_labels`. In this case, you are in charge of making sure that your tick labels actually represent what's on the axis.

---

Note: I have used

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
```

in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from matplotlib 1.1 there's a

```
tight_layout() # or fig.tight_layout() -- depending on the interface
               #                          You are using
```

and it adjusts the widths automatically. It allows to specify padding: see [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/tight_layout_api.html).

Sometimes one needs to adjust the margin manually though: for example when You put legend outside of axes. In this case one can call

```
subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, top=0.9, left=0.1, right=0.95) # or fig.subplots_adjust ...
```

Note though, that both commands has to be called before `savefig` or `show`.